# Contar registros para 3 columnas de estados en misma tabla

Tags: mysql, group-by

Necesito saber cómo hacer múltiples conteos desde una tabla.
Tengo 3 columnas de estado y necesito contar cuántos registros hay por columna por estado (agrupar por estado)

Este sería el resultado que quiero lograr...

```
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|                   | State 1 | State 2 | State 3 |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Answer            | 77      | 0       | 11      |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Calling late      | 100     | 0       | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| No answer         | 22      | 11      | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Payment intention | 11      | 11      | 62      |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Unreachable       | 33      | 0       | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Voicemail         | 22      | 72      | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Wrong phone       | 31      | 0       | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| call back         | 0       | 62      | 0       |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| NULL              | 0       | 140     | 223     |
+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[Script create and data table](https://anonfiles.com/jfLfx44co1/Script_create_table_and_inserts_sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propongo algo así:

```
SELECT states,
  IFNULL(state1,0) state1,
  IFNULL(state2,0) state2,
  IFNULL(state3,0) state3
  FROM (
    SELECT state1 states FROM mora
    UNION 
    SELECT state2 FROM mora
    UNION 
    SELECT state3 FROM mora
  ) c0 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT state1 states,COUNT(*) state1
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(states) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT state2 states,COUNT(*) state2
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1  
  ) c2 USING(states) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT state3 states,COUNT(*) state3
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1
  ) c3 USING(states);
```

Es necesario combinar los tres `GROUP BY`, pero muy importante empezar por una subconsulta que contenga todos los estados para que el `LEFT JOIN` no de deje ninguno atrás.

Para conseguir los ceros, utilizo `IFNULL()`

Si se requiere cualquier aclaración, dejádmela en los comentarios.

Comment: Lo probé!!! Funciona perfecto, tal cual la tabla q pase. GRACIAS!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Te consulto, si tuviese que agregar un campo mas, Base en este caso. Como completaría la query?? base = 'Tributario Mayo 2020'
Se debe agrupar por base también, dado que tengo un lote de mas de 1M de datos.

Comment: Parte del mérito es tuyo: cuando nos pasáis el dataset completo y el resultado que esperáis para esos datos de muestra, nos facilitáis enormemente la labor de responder. Continuemos haciéndolo así de bien: plantea una nueva pregunta con el dataset ampliado y qué esperas obtener en esta ocasión.

Comment: Gracias David, ahi genere una nueva pregunta, casi exacta a esta pero con el formato esperado.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361688/contar-registros-para-3-columnas-de-estados-en-misma-tabla-agrupar-por-estados