# Contar registros para 3 columnas de estados en misma tabla, agrupar por estados y base

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Necesito saber cómo hacer múltiples conteos desde una tabla.
Tengo 3 columnas de estado y necesito contar cuántos registros hay por columna por estado (agrupar por estado), a su vez existe la columna **base**, esta me permite agrupar por un nombre X dado que tengo mas de 1 millon de datos a manipular

Este sería el resultado que quiero lograr...

```
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Base | States            | State 1 | State 2 | State 3 |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Answer            | 77      | 0       | 11      |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Calling late      | 100     | 0       | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | No answer         | 22      | 11      | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Payment intention | 11      | 11      | 62      |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Unreachable       | 33      | 0       | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Voicemail         | 22      | 72      | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | Wrong phone       | 31      | 0       | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | call back         | 0       | 62      | 0       |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| June | NULL              | 0       | 140     | 223     |
+------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[Script create and data table](https://anonfiles.com/jfLfx44co1/Script_create_table_and_inserts_sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece haberte entendido algo así:

```
SELECT base,states,
  IFNULL(state1,0) state1,
  IFNULL(state2,0) state2,
  IFNULL(state3,0) state3
  FROM (
    SELECT base,state1 states FROM mora
    UNION 
    SELECT base,state2 FROM mora
    UNION 
    SELECT base,state3 FROM mora
  ) c0 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT base,state1 states,COUNT(*) state1
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(base,states) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT base,state2 states,COUNT(*) state2
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c2 USING(base,states) LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT base,state3 states,COUNT(*) state3
      FROM mora GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c3 USING(base,states);
```

Pero es que, claro, en el dataset todos los `Base` son `June`, así que podría haber puesto una constante y acertar. Por favor, cambia algún registro en el dataset y comprueba si funciona como debería funcionar.

Tengo que reconocer que hay consultas que son más fáciles de hacer que de explicar.

Comment: Una duda, como funciona el `GROUP BY 1,2`

Comment: Es una simplificación del MySQL para no tener que repetir los campos que pones justo después del `SELECT`, viene en el manual: "Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are integers and begin with 1"  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Sería equivalente a poner `GROUP BY base,state1`

Comment: Todo perfecto David!! La verdad que incluso me hace toda la base de 1M de registros en 4 segundos.
Te puedo consultar, porque no soy un conocedor de sql, si tuviese que pasar parametros, por ej, el nombre de la base, como seria la forma correcta? Seria en el where de cada select?

Comment: También puedes poner el `WHERE` al final, como prefieras. Si tu problema es la velocidad, puedes meter el `WHERE` entre cada  `FROM` y su `GROUP BY`, o bien crear un índice con `ALTER TABLE mora ADD INDEX(base);`

Comment: Gracias, gracias, Muchísimas gracias!!! La verdad no puedo explayar en palabras la cantidad de AYUDA que me brindaste!! Esto me salvo de tener que hacer otras cosas para solucionar un problema. Ni hablar de las explicaciones que adjuntas a tus respuestas!! Salud querido David y gracias nuevamente. Abz

Comment: Realmente me gustaría agradecerte a ti que hubieras planteado la pregunta y reconocer la visión que has tenido de proponer algo que ni siquiera sabías si era alcanzable en MySQL. Muchas veces es más sencillo resolver un problema de la forma ya que sabemos (esas otras cosas de las que hablas), que abrirnos a escuchar nuevas opciones. Bienvenido a la comunidad y por aquí nos seguiremos viendo :)